# How to run a function before page refresh in Angular if statement is true?

Tags: angularjs, reload, route-provider

I have an application with 8 different routes using `$rootProvider`.

If I am on `/signUp` and a page reload is detected, I want to check if `$scope.createAccView = true`. If it is true then run a function.

I tried doing this different ways, by using `$routeChangeStart` and `$routeChangeSuccess` but it did not work.

Mainly the main problem is, if a route change is detected and if `$scope.createAccView = tru`e then I need to run a function before changing the route.

Anybody know how could I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't understand `run a function before page refresh in Angular?` part..why should any one reload a page while he is in SPA?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can use destroy event of scope but it really sounds like your data should be in a service. Provide more details of exactly what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

If you reload the page (using the browser 'reload') the angularjs app will be reinitialized and won't detect any state change

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem this way:

```
window.onunload = unloadPage;
function unloadPage()
{
    var path = $location.path();
    if(path === "/signUp"){
        Auth.$unauth();
    }
}
```